# Zurb Foundation Top Bar Nav not working properly on iPad Landscape only

Tags: zurb-foundation

I have created website using **zurb foundation framework**. I have the top navigation bar for the website which works in almost all browsers on the devices, except **iPad** in **landscape mode**.

The issue is:

when I try to expand submenu from the menu it first opens the another submenu, closes it and then it opens the menu that I touch on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the **[visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html)** foundation provide.

Add this class in your bar:

```
.show-for-landscape   /* Visible for landscape orientation */
```